# Clarification Needs for Container Width Setting

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, width, psd

For my PSD Design the container width is 1136px and i used bootstrap for my design so i decided to set container width is 1166px because the container padding 30px was matched the row padding 30px so it is right way to fixed 1164px or shall i go to 1136px give me a clarification for setting width for container

Answer (score 0):

If you want your site to be responsive you should use Bootstrap breakpoints instead of setting fixed width to your container. Try to not get too attached to your PSD and think of your website as something more fluid.